# Java Error: "; Expected Not a statement "

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) in and Netbeans for my Java project.

While inserting data into the database, it is showing the error:

```
; Expected Not a statement
```

Here is the Java code:

```
public int adduser(String fname,String mname,String lname,String address,
                   String phone,String email,String designation,
                   String subject,String institute,String inemail,
                   String uname,String pwd,String utype)
{
    int n=0;
    try{
        String sql=
          "insert into user(user_name,password,type,specialize,f_name,m_name, " +
          "l_name, address,phone,email,designation,institute,in_email) " +
          "values('"+uname+"','"+pwd+"','"+utype+"','"+subject+"'," + 
          "'"fname"','"mname"','"lname"','"address"','"phone"','"email"','"designation"','"institute"','"inemail"')";
        n = db.modifyingQueries(sql);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return n;
}
```

What does this error mean?  What is wrong with my SQL statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed the concatenation of the string by `+` sign.

```
String sql="insert into user(user_name,password,type,specialize,f_name,m_name,l_name,"
                    + "address,phone,email,designation,institute,in_email)values('"+uname+"','"+pwd+"','"+utype+"','"+subject+"',"
                     + "'"+fname+"','"+mname+"','"+lname+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+designation+"','"+institute+"','"+inemail+"')";
```